# Power BI Report Server Rest API Query String Options

Tags: rest, power-bi-report-server

Does anyone have any documentation on what your query options are when using the PBIRS Rest API?

I have Microsoft Documentation showing my syntax as `{URI-scheme} :// {URI-host} / {resource-path} ? {query-string}` at this page https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-bi/report-server/rest-api

I also have the Rest API documentation provided on that page here https://app.swaggerhub.com/apis/microsoft-rs/PBIRS/2.0#/.

This gives me an idea of the queries I could potentially write
[image]

However, the hyperlinks (shown in picture) take you here http://docs.oasis-open.org/odata/odata/v4.0/odata-v4.0-part1-protocol.html#_Toc445374630 which seem to indicate I should also be able to do several other things such as `$expand`.
[image]

I cannot seem to find any articles or other material that focus on the `? {query-string}` section of the API syntax. The websites I've provided don't allow me to play with the API URL to test what works/doesn't. I'm fumbling around playing with different iterations of the `$expand` which work sometimes, and other times don't. Does anyone have information or articles they can share with me that is focused on this section of syntax of the API? Is there something I missed on any of the provided web sites?

Any help is greatly appreciated.